# Expand k8s journalctl log output

Tags: logging, journaling

Using command

`journalctl -x  kubelet`

I get very long, cut lines; how to unwrap them or access k8s log in other way? (adding --all did not work for me) 
Example:

`-Nov 01 19:56:55 lenovo kubelet[530]: E1101 19:56:55.718234     530 kuberuntime_manager.go:684] init container start failed: ImagePullBackOff: Back-off pulling image "quay.`

Why are there no logs for k8s under /var/logs?

Answer (score 0):

No expanding is actually needed - cursor arrows left/right do scrolling.